# how to make apache server public

Tags: apache, web, public

I want to convert my pc to a web server. I installed centos server and apache server. 
How I can make apache server public? I want to everyone access my web site on my pc via browser.
Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 ways, you can buy a domain and a static IP address for your computer (usually through the service provider) and configure your router and FW to allow access to the machine for port 80.

The other way is to use some sort of dynamic dns service like DynDNS to be able to bind a DNS to a dynamic IP address (you will need to run a daemon to update the account once in a while because your IP may change). The FW and router rules are still needed in this case as well.

After you do one of the these steps everyone should be able to access your apache server on your computer as long as it's on.

Comment: which settings should change apache??

Comment: what do you mean by "change apache" ?